# Transaction declined in django oscar paypal

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal, django-oscar

I have implemented django-oscar-paypal for an ecommerce site and testing it using a test account. If i try to make a shopping greater than Rs.1000 will direct me to an error:

> RESULT=12&PNREF=A11A7D38AB02&RESPMSG=Declined&PREFPSMSG=Review: More than one rule was triggered for Review

The result code getting is 12. I got confused with this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are triggering some rule of a test account on Paypal. Somethings are just not allowed on a test account.

Comment: Is there any limit on amount to purchase as i got error only if the amount is greater than 1000. Otherwise it is ok.

Comment: All I can say is... this has nothing to do with Django or programming.